# How to extract number values from string mix with numbers and characters in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

I am quite new to regular expression. My requirement is to extract number from string that includes mix of numbers and characters. I have tried below codes but I can only get the first number from string.

```
String serialNumber= "000745 TO 000748,00050-00052"
Match match = Regex.Match(serialNumber), @"(\d)+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (match.Success)
{
    int a = Convert.ToInt32(match); // This part not sure how to do
}
```

Expected result is:

```
000745
000748
00050
00052
```

Comment: `(\d+)` with global flag should do that

Comment: In particular this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2221729/477420 from duplicate gives you exact output you are looking for (obviously converting resulting numeric-only strings to integer values will lose leading zeros, so very unclear why you even tried that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string strRegex = @"\d+";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);
string strTargetString = @"000745 TO 000748,00050-00052";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
    // Add your code here
  }

}
```

You need to loop through your matches to get all the matches.